# What is the use of static methods in C#? Please explain with examples

Tags: c#, oop, static

I don't understand the usage of static methods in C#. In which cases should I use them?

Please provide code examples with your explanation.

Comment: Static functions and variables have class-wide scope, while non-static members are associated with an individual instance. Consider a case where you want to count the instances of a class that have been created. You'd create a static int, initialized to zero. In each class constructor, you'd increment it by one. Then you'd provide a static method or property to read the value

Comment: What is the use of *non*-static functions, when would you use those? What is your understanding of their usage? Kind of strange to say you understand instance functions before you understand static functions

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with some terminology. There are *instance* methods and *static* methods. Instance methods belong to an instance of a class or type. Static methods belong to the type, not to any particular instance.

As an example, you can't add to a `List<int>` without an instance of `List<int>`.

```cs
var list = new List<int>(); // creates an instance
list.Add(1);
```

When you call `Add`, you're adding to a specific instance of `List<int>`. You can have multiple instances and add different numbers to each one. It is an instance method.

Sometimes an instance is unnecessary. An example of this is the static [`Math`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math) class which has various static methods like `Sqrt` to get the square root of a number.

```cs
var squareRoot = Math.Sqrt(100);
```

Compare this to `List<T>`s `Add` method which changes the list, and its `Count` property which is different for each instance because each list can have a different number of items.

`Sqrt` does not change anything, and it doesn't depend on the state of the class. You could make `Math` non-static and make `Sqrt` an instance method, but what would be the point? Then you would have to write this code:

```cs
var math = new Math();
var squareRoot = math.Sqrt(100);
```

...but even if you created multiple instances of `Math` the result would always be the same, so what is the point of having instances of `Math`?

Methods that don't depend on the state of an instance or change the state of an instance are good candidates for static methods.

This is not the only use for static methods, but it's a common one. If you don't need an instance of a class for a method to work then the method can be static.

---

Static members can also change a class's static state, as in this example:

```cs
public class Counter
{
    private static int _count;

    public static void Increment()
    {
        _count++;
    }

    public static int Count => _count;
}
```

There are no instances of `Counter`. There's only the type, and when you call `Counter.Increment()` you change the value of `_count` for any code that checks the `Count` property.

We can write static classes that modify their state like this, but there are downsides. If we decide that for some reason we want to count two different things, we can't with the class above. If we could create separate instances of `Counter` then we could increment them separately, just like adding different items to different instances of `List<T>`.

Static methods like this also introduce global state. That means any code throughout an application can potentially call a method and change some static state, and that potentially makes it harder to understand code.

Global state isn't automatically wrong. It might exactly what you want for some reason. But we tend to avoid it because of the way it makes it harder to tell how different parts of the code affect each other by changing and reading the same values.

---

There are no doubt more answers to the question, but this should cover the more common uses of static methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure more knowledgeable persons will give better answers, but here is one anyway. I suppose here that the `static` keyword is understood, and won't discuss static property or fields, only static methods.

C# was born when Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) was very popular. So it was designed so that (almost) everything is an object. This means roughly that you can't really define a function out of the scope of a class. By the way, a "function" defined in a class is called a method.

As you know a class (in the general sense) is supposed, among other things, to associate together related data and functions. But sometimes, you might not have any meaningful data to associate with a function or set of functions. You might just be interested in the function (or a set of functions).

In that case, you don't need an instance, since an instance purpose is to store a state, which you are not interested in. So the solution to is to get rid of the instance by using a static class that will contain static methods.

In that way you get closer to an older programming paradigm: Procedural Programming, which predated OOP.

The classic example is given by the [C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

> A static class can be used as a convenient container for sets of
> methods that just operate on input parameters and do not have to get
> or set any internal instance fields. For example, in the .NET Class
> Library, the static System.Math class contains methods that perform
> mathematical operations, without any requirement to store or retrieve
> data that is unique to a particular instance of the Math class. That
> is, you apply the members of the class by specifying the class name
> and the method name[...].

Here is an example of the use of three static methods, `Abs`, `Floor` and `Round`, defined in the static class `Math`:

```cs
var number = -5.263;  
var absoluteValue = Math.Abs(number);  // 5.263
var floorNumber = Math.Floor(number);  // -6
var roundedNumber = Math.Round(Math.Abs(number)); // 5
```

C# is a multi-paradigm language, and besides OOP, Functional Programming (FP) is partly supported. In FP, functions are the basic building blocks of code. They have no data associated with them. They can take inputs (arguments) and can produce an output (return value). They should not have side effects (this is called purity). To help support these principles, many features were added to C#. One of them, extensions methods, are based on static methods.

Here is a concrete example: the most obvious part of C# that is inspired by functional programming is Linq. Linq could not exist as it is without extensions methods, which are static.

See [the C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) on extension methods.

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
> without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
> modifying the original type. Extension methods are static methods, but
> they're called as if they were instance methods on the extended type.
> For client code written in C#, F# and Visual Basic, there's no
> apparent difference between calling an extension method and the
> methods defined in a type. The most common extension methods are the
> LINQ standard query operators that add query functionality to the
> existing System.Collections.IEnumerable and
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable types.

Here is a Linq example:

```cs
var bestMovies = movies
    .Where(m => m.Rating > 8)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Rating);
```

Here `Where` and `OrderByDescending` are static methods.

So static methods are a very important component of C#, and are heavily used.

Static methods can be used when you only need a simple helper method that does not depend on associated data. They allow simple constructs that can quickly and easily help with redundant code. They are a valuable tool to use in the right circumstances.

Here is an example of a pair of static methods (one is an extension method). You can run it in Linqpad.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var hello = "Hello";
    Console.WriteLine(hello.Decorate("@")); // ====== @HELLO ======
    
    var result = Utils.MyMathFunction(6); 
    Console.WriteLine(result); // 42
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public static class Utils
{
    public static string Decorate(this string text, string decoration)
    {
        return $"====== {decoration}{text.Trim().ToUpper()} ======";
    }
    
    public static double MyMathFunction(double number)
    {
        return (number + 3) * number - 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the Linq methods: these are slightly different, as they are *extension methods* - technically static methods, but used like instance methods defined outside the class.

Comment: Do you mean "Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are static methods, but they're called as if they were instance methods on the extended type." ? This is already stated above.